# HA Proxy fails to start - failed to drop supplementary groups

Tags: proxy, configuration, config, haproxy

I'm working on setting up HAProxy for our servers, and have run into issues while trying to start it.  When I call the haproxy script from /etc/init.d, it only tells me that it failed to starts:

```
Starting haproxy:                                          [FAILED]
```

On running the command `haproxy -db -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`, I get the following:

```
[WARNING] 023/125320 (15540) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:19] : 'option httplog' not usable with frontend 'https' (needs 'mode http'). Falling back to 'option tcplog'.
[WARNING] 023/125320 (15540) : [haproxy.main()] Failed to drop supplementary groups. Using 'gid'/'group' without 'uid'/'user' is generally useless.
[ALERT] 023/125320 (15540) : [haproxy.main()] Cannot set gid 7058355.
```

Option httplog I can fix easily enough, but I have no idea where the `supplementary groups` warning or the `cannot set gid` alert are from.  I'm using version 1.6.7 of haproxy, due to legacy environmental needs, and have the following configuration file:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1   local0
  log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
  #log loghost    local0 info
  maxconn 4096
  #debug
  #quiet
  user <User name here.  Already checked that user exists on server>
  group <Group name here.  Already checked that group exists on server and that user is part of it>

defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  retries 3
  timeout client 50s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 50s
  option dontlognull
  option httplog
  option redispatch
  balance  roundrobin

# Set up application listeners here.

listen admin
  bind 127.0.0.1:22002
  mode http
  stats uri /


frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:4000
  default_backend servers-http

frontend https
  mode tcp
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:4001
  default_backend servers-https


backend servers-http
  server <Server Name Here> <IP Address Here>:4002 weight 1 maxconn 100 check

backend servers-https
  mode tcp
  server <Server Name Here> <IP Address Here>:4003 weight 1 maxconn 100 check
  option ssl-hello-chk
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: [server fault](https://serverfault.com/) is a better place for this question

Comment: I didn't even know there was a stack exchange for servers. I figured it out though.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out this particular issue.  I needed to have the user and owner set to root.

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1   local0
  log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
  #log loghost    local0 info
  maxconn 4096
  #debug
  #quiet
  user root
  group root
```

Comment: i think it will use your local user,eg you set root to ensure it has all probably needed permissions.